# Grafana aggregation by daily

Tags: prometheus, grafana

Hi everyone I have the following data table on grafana.

[image]

How can I make an aggregate by daily via prometheus?

Comment: Please represent your table with text instead of an image if possible. I hope you find an answer to your question soon.